# Is there any way of searching for the complement of another search?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, search

I know that searching for

> votes:10

will return all questions with scores of ten or more.

What I want to know is whether there is a way of searching for questions that don't fit into that category. I want to search for the **complement of votes:10**.

Comment: Seems like they should allow the `-` operator on that one. Basically let `-votes:10` return all questions which do *not* have 10 votes or more.

Comment: I don't think so, but there should be!

Comment: Someone was asking about this in scifi chat a couple days ago. There isn't as of yet, probably better to make this a [feature request].

Comment: @animuson or maybe a !votes:10 operator

Comment: @Conner perhaps `~votes:10`. Makin' it ( •_•)>⌐■-■ (⌐■_■) bitwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible after the next build.  Range operators will support an "end only" syntax: `votes:..9` (or `score:..9`, they're synonyms).